# Change ftp css style

Tags: jquery, html, css, ftp

I am programming a pc managment website but I want to change the style of the ftp:// 
It is included in a iframe but when I want to change something with jQuery I get an cross-domain error: SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http:/ /192.168.0.114:8010" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
The ftp is included with ftp:// 192.168.0.114:21'

I hope that it is possible to change the style because it doesn't fit with the rest of the site.
I am using the IIS7 ftp client of Windows 7

Comment: You can't access or edit content on different domains for security purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer but after a long time of recoding this http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwebftp/ I could use it in my website. Its really easy to use and advanced. The only downside is that it's really old.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to security restrictions, this is unlikely to be possible. If the ftp folder is in a publicly accessible folder (facing the internet), you could make a page like [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/display-styled-directory-contents/) to show the contents and edit that page to make it fit in with your website. Note this uses PHP not just HTML!

Comment: I tried your solution but its to out of date. It wont work good. I found something else that works.

Comment: @Starlight_NL Sorry I couldn't help. Please post the solution you found as an answer to this question because it could hhelp other people in the future!