# How can I feature my FTP server into a website, as if the website is a frame to decorate it?

Tags: html, ftp, embedding

I've been trying to integrate my FTP server into a basic HTML webpage, so it looks a bit better, and it feels more like a cloud storage site. I've tried `<object>`, `<embed>` and `<iframe>`. Here's the details for the sites:

FTP server - "FTP://F-Drive.myftp.org/",
Website - "HTTP://F-Drive.myftp.org/"

Yes, I am aware this is not secure, but I don't use it for anything sensitive.

Here is the code of the page:

```html
<html>
<head>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

    <style>
        .button {
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Century Gothic;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
                
        .button1 {background-color: #ff00ff;}
        </style>

<!--<link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>-->
<title>F-Drive</title>
<section align="center" style="padding: 2%;">
    <img src="favicon.png" alt="F-drive Logo">
</section>
</head>


<body style=background-color:#002c8b;">
<section style="background-color:#10c5fb;">
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Century Gothic"><strong>Welcome to</strong></span></h1>
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff2600;"><span style="font-size:71px"><span style="font-family: Century Gothic"><strong>F-Drive Online Storage</strong></span></span></h1>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff7b00;"><span style="font-family: Century Gothic"><strong>Created by Eddie Farnworth</strong></span></span></h1>
</section>
<div style="background-color:#ffe6cc;color:white;padding:20px">
<section style="background-color:#ffe6cc;">
<div align="center">
<a href="http://F-Drive.myftp.org" class="button button1">Log out</a>
</div>

<body>
    <object data="FTP://F-Drive.myftp.org" width="400" height="300" type="text/html"></object>
</body>

</html>
```

Might be a bit untidy because I'm not massively experienced with HTML.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please clarify what it is you need help with--and also what issue you cannot resolve?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to iframe your FTP resource within a HTML page. I'm not sure though. Could you state what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried and what isn't working please?

Answer (score 0):

Due to security issues it is not really possible to change .
But anyway take a look at this [Change ftp css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263767/change-ftp-css-style)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how would I go about implementing this system on my site?